# Use nginx as reverse proxy for outgoing mail

Tags: nginx, email, reverse-proxy, smtp

We have a production server running a singlepage web-app and a separate proxy server, for security reasons. Every request to our web-app is handled by our reverse proxy (nginx) on the proxy server. So the IP adress of our production server is never visible to outsiders.

Now we need to send (not get) emails from our production server via nodemailer. We would like to send it to mail.proxyserver.com and he should pass it to a new adress. We did this already for normal https request and were able to use header variables to determine the proxy_pass adress (`proxy_pass https://$http_target_ip;`)

**Is it possible to reverse-proxy outgoing emails via nginx, so that a server can send emails over a proxy ithout being visible himself?**

How would the config for this need to look like when sending Emails via smtp over a standard port?

*I took a look at the nginx documentation and various forum posts but atm I cant get bring it together...*

Comment: A reverse SMTP proxy only makes sense for _incoming_ mail, not outgoing mail. Just set up a standard SMTP server in a smarthost configuration.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton. My goal is to send a smtp request (outgoing mail) from the production server over the proxy-server to another smtp server using nginx on the proxy. So that the actual smtp/mail server cannot see the production server IP. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's a lot of trouble to hide an IP address. Don't you have a firewall?

Comment: firewall is in a place and in case of the production server it only allows connections between production and proxy server. could you still help me out on this one? looking for way to just "forward" an smtp-send-request from production server over the proxy (nginx) to a mail server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton do you see any way to do this? thanks! I was hoping to use somehow the proxy_pass command, as I did for normal https requests. We I even was able to pass the target via a header variable to nginx.